# How to populate an entity model using EF raw SQL queries and/or LinQ?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, rawsql, entity-model

I want to populate the entity model below:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public Abc Abc { get; set; }
    public Def Def { get; set; }        
    public List<Ghi> Ghi { get; set; }
}

public class Abc
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}

public class Def
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string OtherString { get; set; }
}

public class Ghi
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int DefID { get; set; }
    public string ThirdString { get; set; }
}
```

With data using EF & some raw SQL queries:

```
using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var abc = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<Abc>(@"SELECT Abc.* FROM XY INNER JOIN Abc ON XY.AbcID = Abc.ID").ToList();
    var def = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<Def>(@"SELECT Def.* FROM XY INNER JOIN Def ON XY.DefID = Def.ID").ToList();
    var ghi = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<Ghi>(@"SELECT Ghi.* FROM XY INNER JOIN Def ON XY.DefID = Def.ID INNER JOIN Ghi ON Def.ID = Ghi.DefID").ToList();
}
```

But I cannot do it like this:

```
var myModel = new MyModel();
myModel.Abc = abc;
myModel.Def = Def;
myModel.Ghi = Ghi;
```

As it would throw me errors such as

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'MyProject.Models.Abc'

So, the questions are:

1) How can I convert a List to a Model or better directly populate a Model instead of a List using raw SQL?

2) I know LinQ can make things easier with less code to write... how can I do it with LinQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is self explainary you should write it like this:

```
var myModel = new MyModel();
myModel.Abc = abc.FirstOrDefault();
myModel.Def = Def.FirstOrDefault();
myModel.Ghi = Ghi;
```

You trying to put collection that your get with `.ToList()` extenstion method to property that define as single model.

Comment: Thank you, Teo! Damn, it was that easy. What about my second question?

Comment: @Tomo actually if you using EF you should be able to map your DB structure to EF entities and then use them instead of plain SQL queries. Check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application) it shows how to generate model from existing db.

Comment: I don't want that, I prefer to write it manually without the unnecessary stuff that comes with the Entity Data Model Wizard. I do the inserts without raw sql, but getting data from db I use raw sql, but I should use LinQ instead.

Comment: You can use linq to sql with this stuff, otherwise you always can use linq to objects with your models after gettin your data from db

Answer (score 0):

try code:

```
var myModel = new MyModel();
using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
  myModel.ABC= (from p in ctx.XYZ
               join q in ctx.Abc on p.AbcId equals q.Id
               select q).FirstOrDefault();
 var result= (from p in ctx.XYZ
               join q in ctx.Def on p.DefId equals q.Id
               select q).ToList();
 myModel.DEF=result.FirstOrDefault();
 myModel.GHI=( from p in result
                join q in ctx.Ghi on p.Id equals q.DefId
                select q).ToList();

}
```